# The getter 'size' isn't defined for the type 'TaskData'

Tags: flutter, code-documentation

This is one of the cases that makes it is difficult to learn flutter.
Here is an example directly from ([code source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-using-nested-models-and-providers/)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:task_management/model/task_data.dart';

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(builder: (context, data, child) {
    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data.size,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final task = data.tasks[index];
            
        // gesture detection
        return GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () => data.removeTask(task),
            child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 5, 8, 5),
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black12,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                    
                // text field
                Text(
                    task.task,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        decoration:
                            task.completed ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                    
                // switch case
                Switch(
                    value: task.completed,
                    onChanged: (c) => data.toggleTask(task),
                ),
                ],
            ),
            ),
        );
        },
    );
    });
}
}
```

But it brings up the inevitable error message: "The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'TaskData.'"
Any easy way to fix this?

Comment: The word `length` isn't even in the piece of code you posted. The error literally means you are writing `length` somewhere to an object that doesn't have a `length`

Comment: I know.
You'd think that, when someone is providing examples, they would at least make sure they work.

Comment: No, I'm telling you. That error can't possibly happen from the code you showed

Comment: Sorry: you're right; I changed it to "length" in my attempt to debug it, but it was originally "size."

Lot of typos today...

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, it actually needs to be

```
    itemCount: data.tasks.length,
```

Comment: "From the looks of it, it actually needs to be"

Yep: that's it. Documentation needs to be updated?

Comment: @user8016440 yeah I think so. I actually made an improvement suggestion on that website to correct it. Hopefully they fix it